# Exporting large table that has been formatted into PDF (or other format) for inclusion into word paper

Tags: gtsummary

May be a rather trivial question that is easy to solve but I'm struggling with exporting the tables that I've been formatting in R for use in my paper (Using the CombinedDemographics table as an example for the code below). Been using the  package to create the tables. Rows keep being cropped and I'm unable to adjust size of the exported file regardless of file type.
Tried ggsave, pdf and all the usual export options from within the viewer pane (adjusting file type and dimensions and aspect ratios). Also tried the <as_gt> example. but doesn't seem to work for me.
May be rather clunky code as I'm just starting learning but seems to be doing the job! Any advice would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
Luke

Code:

```
`#SelectDataset for Demographics
DemographicFactors <- POALAllforR %>%
  select(Age, Sex, Smoker, MI, PVD, CVD, COPD, Diabetes, ASA, ECOGScore, Mortality, COD , Salvaged)
DemographicFactorsILM <- POALAllforR %>%
  select(Age, Sex, Smoker, MI, PVD, CVD, COPD, Diabetes, ASA, ECOGScore, Mortality, COD , InitialLeakManagement)
#createtables for Demographics
tbl_demographics <- DemographicFactors %>%
  tbl_summary(
        by = Salvaged,
        statistic = list(
          all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
          all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"), 
        label = Age ~ "Patient Age") %>%
      add_p(test = all_continuous() ~ "t.test",
            pvalue_fun = function(x) style_pvalue(x, digits = 2))%>%
  add_overall()
tbl_demographics_ILM <- DemographicFactorsILM %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = InitialLeakManagement,
    statistic = list(
      all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
      all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"), 
    label = Age ~ "Patient Age") %>%
  add_p(test = all_continuous() ~ "t.test",
        pvalue_fun = function(x) style_pvalue(x, digits = 2))
tbl_demographics_ILM

#Combine Demographic Tables
CombinedDemographics <- tbl_merge(
  tbls = list(tbl_demographics, tbl_demographics_ILM),                          # combine
  tab_spanner = c("**Salvaged**", "**Initial Leak Management**")) # set header names
CombinedDemographics
CombinedDemographicsExport <- tempfile("CombinedDemographicsExport",fileext = ".docx")
CombinedDemographics %>%
  as_gt()%>%
  gt::gtsave(filename = CombinedDemographicsExport)`
```

Comment: Hi Luke, Welcome to Stackoverflow! I am not sure what you're asking from the community here. Please update your post with a *minimal* reproducible example, aka a reprex https://reprex.tidyverse.org/. Are you asking how to export a gtsummary table to a PDF only? Is your table so large that is spans multiple pages and has incorrect formatting? Provide us an example we can run on our machines and tell us precisely what formatting is not correct or is unexpected.